# WordPress - include sub-categories in category slug

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

The following script outputs an icon image depending on the category slug, I would like to add in child categories of the 'Service' category - so that these will show the icon too. Would this ideally be in the form of an array?

```
<?php
   $category = get_the_category(); 
   $category_slug = $category[0]->slug;

   if($category_slug == 'service') {
?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon/service.png" alt="service"><span>Service</span>

<?php
}
?>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the current problem?

Comment: The script works with parent categories but not child categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get that data and that will be array. here is a piece of code that will elaborate a bit.

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category(); 
$category_slug = $category[0]->slug;

if($category_slug == 'service') {
$category_id = $category->term_id;
?>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon/service.png"    alt="service"><span>Service</span>

<?php
$children = get_term_children($category_id, '**your taxonomy name here**');
foreach($children as $child) {
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/icon/service.png"    alt="service">
}
}
?>
```

Now, paste this code in place of your code and replace **your taxonomy name here** with your taxonomy name. Now, your sub categories will be taking your desired image. For further reading [please visit codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children)